# Java data type for holding e164 phone number format

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Is there any data type in java for holding E164 international phone number format?

I dont want to store the value in a string and then validate. I would like to simply define my variable in this particular data type.

Comment: You can always create your own Custom type.

Comment: You may have a look at [this Google library](http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/).

Comment: @Guillaume Poussel, Is there any built-in api

Comment: Nope, that would be too specific.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of Google's [libphonenumber](https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/) api.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, i can't add this library as a dependency in my project. Is there any built-in java api?

Comment: No, i don't think so.